# SaveFileDialog not displaying

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

EDITED CODE/QUESTION.  BEGININVOKE IS NOT LONGER ON THE TABLE.  I'm having trouble getting a SaveFileDialog to show its dialog.  When I call ShowDialog normally I get no response at all. The code falls through and acts like the SFD was never called in the first place.  I also tried running this inside another thread.  Same problem.  When I run it inside the main_load() routine everything works fine.  I'm using .NET 4.0.  **I get the feeling this is happening because I'm calling the SFD code as part of an process exited event.**  MessageBox.Show() works fine!!!  My sample code is shown below.  Does anyone know what could be causing this error?  Thanks!

```
    procConvert.Exited += new EventHandler(ConversionExited);//inside another routine

    private void ConversionExited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try{    
        //works fine
        MessageBox.Show("OverWrite old Gcode file " + NewGcodeName, "Warning File Exist",MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Question,MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);//works fine

        SaveFileDialog SFD = new SaveFileDialog();
        SFD.Filter = "text files (*.gcode)|*.gcode|All files (*.*)|*.*";  //set up filter for gcode and all

        DialogResult result = SFD.ShowDialog();                           //show dialog

        if (result != DialogResult.OK) return;
        NewGcodeName = SFD.FileName;
        if (File.Exists(NewGcodeName + "1")) File.Delete(NewGcodeName + "1");//erase the destination
        System.IO.File.Move(NewGcodeName, NewGcodeName + "1");//copy to backup location, smart thing to do would be to make like 5 backups then toss 
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
          //handle exception
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question is what do you mean by normally.

Comment: You are calling BeginInvoke() at the wrong time.  Whatever *this* might be, its window isn't created yet.  Never make a dialog popup from nowhere, far too likely that the user accidentally closes it.  It needs to be triggered by *something* the user does.  Which help you fall in the pit of success, pretty unlikely then you'll call BeginInvoke() at the wrong time.

Comment: @E-Bat: SFD.ShowDialog(); //without the BeginInvoke nonsense.

Comment: Ok As @HansPassant said, it sounds as if you are trying to open the dialog from a non yet loaded/initialized control and suspect that the catch block is silencing the problem, post the whole relevant code to get more context on this issue.

Comment: @Leppie, what did you edit?

Comment: @DanGifford: Your question does not use or require C# 4.0 specific features. Tag was removed.

Comment: mm I see from your edit "I get the feeling this is happening because I'm calling the SFD code as part of an process exited event."  Post more code to see what is going on

Comment: @E-Bat: more code just posted.

Comment: @HansPassant: I created another thread with the code snippet in it.  Should that have been sufficient to run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the thread.  Somehow C# knew that I was calling the SFD from an exiting routine even when I started another thread.  I ran everything from a timer task routine with a flag to turn the SFD on/off and everything ran perfectly.  Thanks for all the help everyone.

Comment: Today I had a similiar problem where in the customer's code the FileSave dialog should have been shown from an async procedure.
But the calling procedure (of the async procedure) was already finished.
Our solution was to turn the async procedures into regular procedures and everything was fine then.
The only reason for the async procedures was a communication via HTTP. But this could also be turned into sync calls by requesting the result of the response thread.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `SaveFileDialog` on a different thread from the one it was created on.
This is *not allowed.*

For a start, you could put the first two lines and the `NewGcodeName = SFD.FileName;` inside the delegate definition.  But then you'll still have the problem that `BeginInvoke` is intentionally asynchronous, so your delegate won't have finished running by the time you try to use the `result` variable.  To solve this problem, try using `Invoke` instead of `BeginInvoke`.

Edit: this answer assumes that the code shown is running on a different thread from the GUI.  If it's not, this answer makes no sense, but then I'd ask why you're using `BeginInvoke` at all...

Edit 2: after reading your question and the comments more carefully, I realize that these problems (though they need to be addressed) aren't actually what's causing the error message you posted.  That error message is telling you that the `Form` or other `Control` in whose class this code is running hasn't been shown yet (doesn't have a window handle).  You'll need to fix that, too, to have a working solution.

Comment: I understand and appreciate your comments, but I can't even get anything to display on the screen.  The BeginInvoke is definitely NOT the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Please format your code better. It's hart to read it.

And why would you use `BeginInvoke` here?

The problem is that you call `BeginInvoke` before the form/control is actually created (I guess you call it inside the constructor). Try to move your code to a location which is called after the form/control is created or remove the `BeginInvoke`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat lousy answer, but I had this problem on a W10 machine that would just spin and spin. It may have had something to do with the initial directory that the dialog was pointed to. Restarted the PC, and things are much improved. Not the answer I'd want, but maybe the answer you need.

Answer (score -1):

SaveFileDialog SFD = new SaveFileDialog();
SFD.Filter = "text files (*.gcode)|*.gcode|All files (*.*)|*.*";

To open dialog use

SFD.ShowDialog();